# Group Apache log rows by URLs with sed or awk?

Tags: awk, logs, apache-httpd

Given a file `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log` like this:

```
example.com:443 1.1.1.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:12:00:00 +0000] "GET /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm12 HTTP/1.1" 200 1000 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel...
example.com:443 2.2.2.2 - - [25/Jan/2021:12:00:00 +0000] "GET /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm13 HTTP/1.1" 200 1000 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel...
example.com:443 33.33.33.33 - - [25/Jan/2021:12:00:00 +0000] "GET /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm14 HTTP/1.1" 200 1000 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel...
example.com:443 4.4.4.4 - - [25/Jan/2021:12:00:00 +0000] "GET /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm12 HTTP/1.1" 200 1000 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel...
```

how to agglomerate the IPs "grouped by" URLs?

Example:

```
 /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm12
     1.1.1.1
     4.4.4.4
 /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm13
     2.2.2.2
 /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm14
     33.33.33.33
```

I know we can probably use `awk` to extract certain columns, but then how to do the "group by"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{a[$8]=a[$8] "\n\t" $2} END{for (url in a) print url, a[url]}' file
```

The array `a` is initially empty.

- `{a[$8]=a[$8] "\n\t" $2}` extends the value of the element `a[$8]` by a newline and a tab followed by the 2nd field.
- The `END` block is only carried out after the whole file has been parsed. For each key in the array, the key (`url`) and the associated value (`a[url]`) are printed.

Output:

```
/abc/def/ghi?token=jklm14
        33.33.33.33
/abc/def/ghi?token=jklm12
        1.1.1.1
        4.4.4.4
/abc/def/ghi?token=jklm13
        2.2.2.2
```

Comment: Side remark: is it possible to avoid repetition? i.e. if `1.1.1.1` visits ten times the same URL, it should appear once in the report @Quasímodo.

Comment: Indeed, Awk is awesome although Awkward. Re. 2nd comment, this would do it I think: `awk 'a[$8]!~"\t"$2"$" {a[$8]=a[$8] "\n\t" $2} END{for (url in a) print url, a[url]}' file`.

Comment: maybe we can test if `(a[$8]+"\n") !~  ($2 + "\n")`   (pseudo code, I don't know the syntax)  to make sure `4.4.4.4\n` is present or not. What do you think?

Comment: @Basj Yes, that is what my suggestion in last comment does. `\n` is `$` in regex, and I also match the tab.